# change image src in div using .attr() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change all image sources in `HTML` using `jQuery`

I have the below div :

```
<div id="image_list">

    <a href="images/Image1.jpg" title="Image 1">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image2.gif" title="Image 2">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
    </a>
    <a href="images/Image3.gif" title="Image 3">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image3.gif" alt="Image 3">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image4.gif" title="Image 4">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image4.gif" alt="Image 4">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image5.gif" title="Image 5">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image5.gif" alt="Image 5">
    </a>

</div>
```

and I have this jQuery function to change all the images in the div after 2 seconds when the document loads:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        alert("DFDF");
        $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');

    }

}, 2000);
```

links is an array of the `a` tag `links = $listNode.find('a'),`

and `$listNode` is `$listNode = $('#image_list')`

the function is alerting `DFDF` not not changing the image source.

what is the problem in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: `this` is referring to `window` inside setTimeout() callback...

Comment: Try `$('img').each(function () {
 this.src = '1.png';
});` if you want to change all image sources..

Comment: @RayonDabre beware, src property expect an absolute path (not sure how this is handled cross browser regarding setter)

Comment: @A.Wolff, `src` returns absolute path, you can set sources of relative path..I have tested it..Correct me if I am wrong!

Comment: @RayonDabre I think you are right but i'm not sure ;)

Comment: It can be relative or absolute, for absolute prefix with a `/` so `/images/back.jpg` is `root/images..`, `images/back.jpg` is relative

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for` doesn't set `this`, so `$(this)` refers to the global `window` object, not the current element of the iteration. Use `.each`:

```
links.each(function() {
    alert("DFDF");
    $(this).find("img").attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');
});
```

But you don't need to iterate at all, because jQuery modifier functions will operate on a collection:

```
links.find("img").attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');
```

Comment: Looks like he does need to iterate if he is to achieve the requirement:  *..to change all the images in the div **after 2 seconds** when the document loads.*

Comment: @PeterKA `.attr()` iterates automatically.

Comment: You're right, I probably read too much into the 2 sec part. It sounded like one image every 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to iterate every element, jquery will do this for you:

```
setTimeout(function () {
        $('#image_list img').attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');
}, 2000);
```

Incidentally, I doubt `this` means what you think it means in your code above.

Comment: exactly , I though `this` is the element in the array not the window , thank you for you help

Answer (score 1):

Use an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression) as below to change the src of an image every 2 seconds after the page loads:

```
$(function() {
    $('#image_list .img').each(function(i,img) {
        var tm = i * 2000;
        (function( time, image ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(image).attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');
            }, time );
        })( tm, img );
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    var imgsrc = 'http://aspnethosting2go.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/feature1.png';
    $('#image_list .img').each(function(i,img) {
        var tm = i * 2000;
        (function( time, img ) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(img).attr('src', imgsrc).css('width', '100px');
            }, time );
        })( tm, img );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_list">

    <a href="images/Image1.jpg" title="Image 1">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image2.gif" title="Image 2">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
    </a>
    <a href="images/Image3.gif" title="Image 3">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image3.gif" alt="Image 3">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image4.gif" title="Image 4">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image4.gif" alt="Image 4">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image5.gif" title="Image 5">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image5.gif" alt="Image 5">
    </a>

</div>
```

However, if all you want is to change all the images at the same time, 2 seconds after the page loads the use this:

```
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_list .img').attr('src', 'images/back.jpg');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    var imgsrc = 'http://aspnethosting2go.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/feature1.png';
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#image_list .img').attr('src', imgsrc).css('width','100px');
    }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="image_list">

    <a href="images/Image1.jpg" title="Image 1">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image1.jpg" alt="Image 1">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image2.gif" title="Image 2">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image2.gif" alt="Image 2">
    </a>
    <a href="images/Image3.gif" title="Image 3">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image3.gif" alt="Image 3">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image4.gif" title="Image 4">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image4.gif" alt="Image 4">
    </a>

    <a href="images/Image5.gif" title="Image 5">
        <img class="img" src="images/Image5.gif" alt="Image 5">
    </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all `img` tags inside `image_list` like this:

```
$("#image_list img")
```

Just extend it to change the `src` attribute of all selected elements like this:

```
$('#image_list img').attr('src', 'images/back.jpg')
```

Answer (score -2):

Use a selector and you wont need to iterate.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $("#image_list img").attr("src","images/back.jpg");
},2000);
```

Comment: this will set every image on the page to back.jpg. This isn't what the Op wants to do

Comment: Please don't just dump code as an answer. If it's not explained, it's a bad answer.

Comment: I was editing my answer.  I postes the code accidentally before explaining.